# How to use svg 'use' statement with Rails sprockets asset helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, sprockets

I have an svg in an external file that I want to reference with a use statement in Rails.

If I do:

```
%svg
  %use{"xlink:href" => "assets/icon.svg#test"}
```

which generates the html:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="assets/icon.svg#test"></use>
</svg>
```

Everything works as expected.

However I want this to be able to work with sprockets asset versioning in a similar way to how image_tag works.

I tried to do:

```
%svg
  %use{"xlink:href" => image_url("icon.svg#test")}
```

This generates the html:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/icon.svg#test"></use>
</svg>
```

The asset certainly exists at http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/icon.svg, but the icon does not show.

What am I doing wrong? How do I use sprockets asset helpers with svg use statements?

Comment: What UA are you using. This would work on Firefox but there are UAs that don't support external `<use>`.

Answer (score 0):

Asset cannot exist at 0.0.0.0, it is not a real ip, you need to set `config.action_controller.asset_host`

In development `127.0.0.1`(loopback ip) will do

Comment: The prooblem still exist even if asset_host is set to127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a cross origin browser security issue.

Google chrome actually gives a message that helps with this. (I was previously using firefox so didn't notice this...)

Unsafe attempt to load URL http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/icon.svg from frame with URL http://localhost:5000/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

The domain names much match for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this can be fixed by using **`image_path`** instead of `image_url`. That way you should get a **relative link to the SVG file**, i.e. precisely the same output as in your raw HTML, possibly with just the asset hash added to the file name.